# iOS 10: can't get authorization to use images in MessagesExtensions app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I have been trying to access the PhotoLibrary in a Messages Extension app I am creating. I know that since iOS10, you need to include the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in your info.plist, and I have done it. In fact, I created a test app that isn't a Messages Extension app, just a single view app, and it works fine: when the UIImagePickerController is called, the app asks for access to pictures, like it should. However, in my Messages Extension app, the code crashes before the app can ask for permission, even though the info.plist is exactly the same as for the test app.

Is there something specific about Messages Extension apps that could be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in my Messages extension by just adding NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to the Info.plist file for the app itself--not the Info.plist for the extension.